# Back link to show page from nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Schedule page that is nested under events and I would like a link so that users can go back to the event show page but I get an error.

#### Error

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'
```

#### Routes

```
resources :events do
  resources :sessions, path: "schedule", only: [:index]
end
```

#### View

```
<%= link_to "Back to Event", @event_path(@event) %>
```

#### Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :find_event

  def index
    @sessions = Session.all
  end

  private

  def find_event
    @event = Event.find_by(slug: params[:event_id])
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= link_to "Back to Event", event_path(@event) %>
```

(`event_path` is a method)

or simply:

```
<%= link_to "Back to Event", @event %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Marek is` correct -

---

Something more to note is that if you ever want to send to a `nested` resource (I.E  you want to show the `session`), you'd need to use the likes of:

```
 session_path(@session, @event) #-> notice the two objects, not a single one
```

Currently, you'd just need to pass the single object, but in the event you wanted to use a nested route, you'd have to send the `nested` object & its parent object too